# Is there a tool to test Videos in a Mobile App

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, appium, open-source

I am working on a Mobile App project and I am particularly focused on the Video module of it. Scenario I am looking to Automate. is there a open source tool that can do this

Scroll Down to the Video module in the App

Click on the Video

It makes a Get request--> Gets the playlist from the server

See how much time does it take to load the Ad in the player

After Ad is done --. verify If the Video "Get" Call is made and Video starts Playing

Comment: Web (responsive design), hybrid, or native app?

Comment: this is a Hybrid App

Comment: you can compare this with Weather App we have on every iphone in the US .. it almost similar to it

Answer (score 2):

[Appium](http://appium.io/) would probably fit the bill. It uses the iOS simulator (comes with XCode) to run Selenium tests. For Android it uses the Android SDK (comes with Android Studio).

Comment: I have tried Appium but when you have API calls to capture its not very efficient to capture API calls in real time. Had it been only UI of app Appium is the answer.

Comment: Yeah, to capture network traffic you will need to setup a proxy. I use the Fiddler Core with Telerik Test Studio, which now supports iOS (Android coming soon).

Answer (score 1):

Common UI testing tools (Appium and others) will answer most of your requirements except for

> Video starts Playing

This is tricky and can be achieved to some degree depending on the level of confidence you require.

The simplest solution is using the UI tool to get a few screenshots spaced in time, than compare them to each other (verifying that they are different enough)
or to the source video.

More complex solutions would capturing the actual video either on the device or externally, for example using a high speed camera or HDMI cable.